# Qt library link errors in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, linker-errors, qmake

Project builds fine on Linux however has problem linking in Windows.

### 1st issue:

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ...
LNK1120: 21 unresolved externals
```

`.pro` file contains:

```
isEmpty(IDE_BUILD_TREE): IDE_BUILD_TREE = ../../qt-creator-debug
LIBS += -L$${IDE_BUILD_TREE}/lib/qtcreator/plugins -lMyLibrary
```

> **Note.** `MyLibrary` deployed to `$${IDE_BUILD_TREE}/lib/qtcreator/plugins` before build. Building with Qt 5.10.1 and MSVC 2015.

What is the problem/trick here? How to solve?

---

### 2nd issue:

In the library `.pro` file `VERSION` variable is defined and resulting library has name `MyLibrary1.lib`. Thereafter I get error:

```
:-1: error: LNK1181: cannot open input file 'MyLibrary.lib'
```

What is better way to solve the problem here: remove `VERSION` or fix `.pro` file? How?

---

### 3rd issue:

Another link error:

```
mydialog.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 
"struct QMetaObject const MyLibrary::staticMetaObject" 
(?staticMetaObject@MyLibrary@@3UQMetaObject@@B)
```

Error happen because of the following line in code (disappears when commented out):

#### mydialog.cpp:

```
    QMetaEnum myEnum = QMetaEnum::fromType<MyLibrary::MyEnumClass>();
```

#### mylibrary.h:

```
namespace MyLibrary {

Q_NAMESPACE

enum class MYLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT MyEnumClass {
...
};

Q_ENUM_NS(MyEnumClass)
...
} // namespace MyLibrary
```

And how to solve the 3rd one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1st issue fix:

My bad: error caused by missed `MYLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT` in some classes' declarations, which defined in global header as:

```
#if defined(MYLIBRARY_LIBRARY)
#  define MYLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MYLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

Without `MYLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT` builds fine in Linux and Mac but fails in Windows.

---

### 2nd issue fix:

Possible solution - add to `.pro` file line:

```
win32:CONFIG += skip_target_version_ext
```

or

```
win32:TARGET_EXT = .dll
```

to set the output filename without the major version number on Windows. However I see, for example, Qt Creator plugins link libraries with major version number without a problem. How to do this?

---

### 3rd issue fix:

Need to prepend `Q_NAMESPACE` declaration with `MYLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT` as well:

```
namespace MyLibrary {

MYLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT Q_NAMESPACE

enum class MYLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT MyEnumClass {
...
};

Q_ENUM_NS(MyEnumClass)
...
} // namespace MyLibrary
```

Comment: @PatrickParker I will extend and complete the answer when get more info. Just added the note to keep useful info for the 1st issue solving.

Comment: @PatrickParker The OP isn't adding information to his post - he's giving a partial answer. I'm voting "looks OK" for this one because it's an actual attempt to answer the question.

Comment: ok, the phrase "my bad" sounded like you made a mistake with the question itself. maybe a poor word choice there.

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich thanks, the 3rd fix was the solution for me.